# XML to INI transform

Tags: xml, xslt, converters, transform, ini

Hi I'm new to xslt and I have the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<asset xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" startDate="2014-07-18T16:10:10.5677128-03:00">
<items xsi:type="logicalDiskInfo" freeSpace="94275883008" size="175648010240" deviceID="C:" />
 <items xsi:type="logicalDiskInfo" freeSpace="193907666944" size="314571747328" deviceID="D:" />
 <items xsi:type="monitor" availability="8" caption="Generic PnP Monitor" />
 <items xsi:type="monitor" availability="8" caption="Generic PnP Monitor" />
</asset>
```

and I want to convert it to INI format:

```
[logicalDiskInfo 0001]
freeSpace=94275883008
size=175648010240
deviceID=C:

[logicalDiskInfo 0002]
freeSpace=94275883008
size=175648010240
deviceID=C:

[monitor 0001]
availability=8
caption=Generic PnP Monitor

[monitor 0002]
availability=8
caption=Generic PnP Monitor
```

it would be too much effort to do that conversion ?

I was wondering if I should do a loop to each item and then use choose to see what kind of item I am dealing with and in the end create the ini nodes.

I have found a few samples and I was able to see how they work but nothing like that before.

**Sample XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<asset xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" startDate="2014-07-18T16:10:10.5677128-03:00">
<items xsi:type="networkCfg" macaddress="B8:CA:3A:FE:A8:93" description="Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller" adaptertype="Ethernet 802.3" speed="100000000" netconnectionstatus="2" />
<items xsi:type="networkCfg" macaddress="AC:7B:A1:C8:B8:C0" description="Adaptador Virtual Direto Wi-Fi da Microsoft" adaptertype="Ethernet 802.3" speed="9223372036854775807" netconnectionstatus="0" />
<items xsi:type="computerSystem" dnshostname="NOTE0001" domain="a.com.br" bootupstate="Normal boot" powersupplystate="3" thermalstate="3" manufacturer="Dell Inc." model="Vostro 5470" wakeuptype="6" />
</asset>
```

**Sample XSL**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>
<xsl:value-of select="asset/items/computerSystem/@dnshostname"/><xsl:value-of select="asset/@startDate"/><br/>
[Request]<br />
Items=<xsl:value-of select="count(asset/items)"/><br />
<xsl:for-each select="asset/items"><br />
[Network <xsl:number value="position()" format="0001" />]<br />
Name=<xsl:value-of select="@description"/><br />
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="@netconnectionstatus = '0'">
  Status="Disconnected"<br />
</xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="@netconnectionstatus = '1'">
  Status="Connecting"<br />
</xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="@netconnectionstatus = '2'">
  Status="Connected"<br />
</xsl:when>
  </xsl:choose>
MAC=<xsl:value-of select="@macaddress"/><br />
</xsl:for-each>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
2014-07-18T16:10:10.5677128-03:00
[Request]
Items=3

[Network 0001]
Name=Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
Status="Connected"
MAC=B8:CA:3A:FE:A8:93

[Network 0002]
Name=Adaptador Virtual Direto Wi-Fi da Microsoft
Status="Disconnected"
MAC=AC:7B:A1:C8:B8:C0

[Network 0003]
Name=
MAC=
```

Any help will be appreciated,

Thx

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you provide a small sample of what you have tried?

Comment: Hi Phill, thanks for your answer, I will update the post with my sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are transforming **items** elements into separate blocks, you can start off with a template that matches the **items** element

```
<xsl:template match="items">
```

Within this, you can do the first line as follows:

```
<xsl:text>[</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="concat(@xsi:type, ' ')" />
<xsl:number format="0000" />
<xsl:text>]&#10;</xsl:text>
```

Then, you want a line for each attribute, so select them as follows:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
```

Then, you have a template that matches attributes when you can output their name and value:

```
<xsl:template match="@*">
   <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
   <xsl:text>=</xsl:text>
   <xsl:value-of select="94275883008" />
   <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

You would also need a template to ignore **xsi:type** attributes, because you have already processed these in the main **items** template

```
<xsl:template match="@xsi:type" />
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >
   <xsl:output method="text"/>
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

   <xsl:template match="items">
       <xsl:text>[</xsl:text>
       <xsl:value-of select="concat(@xsi:type, ' ')" />
       <xsl:number format="0000" />
       <xsl:text>]&#10;</xsl:text>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
       <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
   </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@xsi:type" />

    <xsl:template match="@*">
       <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
       <xsl:text>=</xsl:text>
       <xsl:value-of select="." />
       <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi Tim C, I changed this line <xsl:value-of select="94275883008" /> to  <xsl:value-of select="." /> and it works fine, but I needed to reset the counter to each item on INI. Your code did helped me alot thanks!

Comment: Sorry about that! I have corrected by XSLT to correctly do `<xsl:value-of select="." />` as you mentioned!

Comment: Thanks once again. Cheers!